# How do I exclude a PR build as resource to a dependent pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I am having an azure build pipeline that builds an app - let's call it App2 - and includes the output of another build that has build another app - App1 - where App2 is depending on. But I do not want to include App1 builds based on a pull-request (PR), only want a build based on the code in the branch the PR merges to.

So, how do I exclude a PR build as resource to a dependent pipeline?

Comment: How exactly one pipeline includes the other? Is it classic or yaml pipelines?

Comment: It's a yaml based build pipeline.

Comment: You could use build variable `Build.Reason` to find out how the build was triggered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services

Comment: Or add a build trigger to yaml to only run for defined branches like master or development.

Comment: Going to invistigate your suggestion on using variable `Build.Reason`.

Comment: Update: it now appears to be fixed by setting the branch parameter to __development__ on the pipeline resource section at the start of our build pipeline yaml.  For example: `- pipeline: pipeline_reference_name / source: pipeline_name / branch: development`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
It appears to be fixed by setting the branch parameter to *development* on the pipeline resource section at the start of our build pipeline yaml.  For example:

```
  - pipeline: pipeline_reference_name
    source: pipeline_name
    branch: development
```